# Is it a bad practice to use multiple vendor tags in one element?

Tags: html, css, vendor-prefix

For example I have:

```
div.subscribe input[type="text-field"]::-webkit-input-placeholder,
div.subscribe input[type="text-field"]::-o-input-placeholder,
div.subscribe input[type="text-field"]::-moz-input-placeholder {
        padding-left: 20px;
}
```

Is it a bad practice or even a valid possibility to condense vendor prefixes? Thanks ahead of time.

**Edit:**

Is it an available possibility to use the vendor prefixes in one class vs multiple classes using different prefixes

Comment: What has ethics to do with this?

Comment: In most cases, not really. It doesn't really affect performance in this case, and might be required for your code to work cross-platform.

Comment: I guess that was a little to contentious of an adjective. Changed the title!

Comment: I find my self not explaining well enough, sorry about that. I was wondering if its an available possibility to use the vendor prefixes in one class vs multiple classes using different prefixes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vendor Prefixes are provided because different browser render some part of css  style sheet code differently. So in order to keep you page look consistent across all the major browser we use vendor prefixes.If the part of the code you are writing renders same on all major browser there is no need of using multiple vendor tags in one element. you can simply use

```
div.subscribe input[type="text-field"]::placeholder{
    padding-left: 20px;
}
```

So it is a bad practice if it is case as explained above because there will be unnecessary extra lines of code which logically does nothing.

**EDIT**

`::placeholder` pseudo class is still not stable. Refer [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::placeholder).
Hence for your case you have to use vendor prefixes till the working draft is finalized and fully supported by major browsers.